# React Native Branch.io deep-link Not Navigating to a Specific Screen( React Native Navigation V6), When App Kill/Close

Tags: javascript, react-native, deep-linking, branch.io

I am implementing branch.io deep linking in my project, I have configured the branch for deep-linking as per the document and with the help of other references like: [React Navigation v5: How to use with Branch.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64545934/react-navigation-v5-how-to-use-with-branch-io)

[How to navigate from linking (deep linking with branch.io) when navigator hasn't been created yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68959522/how-to-navigate-from-linking-deep-linking-with-branch-io-when-navigator-hasnt)

When I clicked on branch link app opens, but not redirecting to specific screen, below are the warning I am receiving in terminal

**The navigation state parsed from the URL contains routes not present in the root navigator. This usually means that the linking configuration doesn't match the navigation structure. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links for more details on how to specify a linking configuration.**

And this is the response of params I am getting from branch.io link(App is configured as universal link in branch dashboard)

{"$canonical_url": "https://myApp.test-app.link/StartupDetailReport", "$marketing_title": "deeplinktest15", "$og_description": "deepdescription", "$one_time_use": false, "+click_timestamp": 1668166318, "+clicked_branch_link": true, "+is_first_session": false, "+match_guaranteed": true, "+rn_cached_initial_event": true, "~campaign": "goldy2", "~channel": "deal", "~creation_source": 1, "~feature": "marketing", "~id": 1119283322135719300, "~marketing": true, "~referring_link": "https://myApp.test-app.link/CbCDkMqxQub", "~tags": ["dfdf"]}

And below is my complete code of App.js for navigationContainer configuration

`

```
import React from 'react';
import {Linking, Text} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import HomeScreen from './src/HomeScreen';
import ChatScreen from './src/ChatScreen';
import DealScreen from './src/DealScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './src/ProfileScreen';
import branch from 'react-native-branch';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const config = {
  screens: {
    HomeTab: {
      screens: {
        Home: 'home',
        Chat: {
          path: 'feed',
        },
        Deal: 'StartupDetailReport',
      },
    },
    Profile: 'user',
  },
};

const linking = {
  prefixes: ['myApp://', 'https://myApp.test-app.link'],

  subscribe(listener) {
    branch.subscribe(({error, params, uri}) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('Error from Branch: ' + error);
        return;
      }

      if (params['+non_branch_link']) {
        const nonBranchUrl = params['+non_branch_link'];
        // Route non-Branch URL if appropriate.
        return;
      }

      if (!params['+clicked_branch_link']) {
        // Indicates initialization success and some other conditions.
        // No link was opened.
        return;
      }

      // A Branch link was opened
      const url = params.$canonical_url;

      listener(url);

    });

    return () => {
      branch.unsubscribe();
    };
  },
  config,
};

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function HomeTab() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Chat" component={ChatScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Deal" component={DealScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking} fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeTab">
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeTab" component={HomeTab} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

`

I am expecting that when I click on branch link it should take me to this "StartupDetailReport" Screen

**Note:** My app is working correctly when app is in background mode, once I kill/close the app and open from branch link its not working as expected.

Please Hepl me I don't know what's wrong with my code
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you need to also use the async getInitialURL()`. It's specifically used for when the app is initially opened.

So something like this should work for you as it did for me:

```
const linking = {
  prefixes: ...,
  subscribe() { ... },
  async getInitialURL() {


    const params = await branch.getLatestReferringParams();
    if (params.$canonical_url) return params.$canonical_url


    // As a fallback, you may want to do the default deep link handling
    const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();

    return url;
  }
}
```